can not connect to PostgreSQL via Laravel database is up and running and can connect via pgadmin
I'm in a difficult situation where I tried so many times but my Laravel application not getting connected to any of the PostgreSQL databases
First I tried to create an AWS PostgreSQL database and tried to connect I got
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432 error.
Then I thought something wrong with the AWS firewall so after wasting some time I moved to hostinger vps.
Where I have hosted my Laravel application. I installed Postgres and pgadmin web-versions there. I could successfully connect to Postgres via pgadmin but I couldn't connect to the database via the Laravel application.
Then I tried to use same posgtgres credentials on my local environment clone of the Laravel application and it worked without issues.
Then I created a separate Postgres database in google cloud and again tried to connect it via Laravel application hosted in Hostinger but that also got failed.
As I earlier mentioned I have the pgadmin installed in Hostinger VPS, so I tried to connect to the google cloud Postgres database via pgadmin. It got connected without any issues.
Anyway I still couldn't connect my Laravel application to get connected with any of these Posgres databases.
I"m getting the same error always

QLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is
The server running on host "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX" and accepting TCP/IP
connections on port 5432?

I have checked Laravel env for many many times, and as I do successfully connect to the database in my local environment I can guarantee that I did the config and credential setting in the .env file correctly.
As I can connect using pgadmin the credentials are also 100% correct.
In Google I have add the IP address of the VPS and the C-panel shared IP address as connection networks.
Exact clone of the local environment source code exists in the VPS C-panel.
I did PHP artisan optimize after updating the .env
I'm out of options now. :(
Please enlighten me on how to over come this issue.

Maybe your laravel application is not taking env variable directly. please try to print your env variable using dd and check it is taking env or not?
